# Unit converter, users choice between km or miles

Tags: python-2.7, converters

```
print "Hello! This is a unit converter between km and miles."
km = " "
miles = " "
if km:
    print "Please enter a number of kilometers that you'd like " \
          "to convert into miles. Enter only a number!"
    km = float(raw_input("Kilometers: "))
    km = miles * 1.609
    print "{0} kilometers is {1} miles.".format(km, miles)

else:
    print "Please enter a number of miles that you'd like " \
          "to convert into kilometers. Enter only a number!"
    miles = float(raw_input("Miles: "))
    miles = km * 0.621
    print "{0} miles is {1} kilometers.".format(miles,km)
```

I'm making simple unit converter and I want that user can choose which unit to convert. I know how to make converting,but I've got a problem because I don't know how to put a code,so that user can choose between miles or kilometers.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to get [`input`](https://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html#the-input-function) from the user, maybe something like:

```
response = input('Enter km or miles: ')

if response == 'km':
    # convert km to miles
else:
    # convert miles to km
```

Comment: Thx, that work. In line "   km = miles * 1.609 " i get an error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare strings.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Sorry, my brain wasn't completely on yesterday.

Comment: @IvanM, from what I can tell, what you actually want is `miles = km * 1.609`, which converts the km the user entered to miles.  Also, don't forget to accept the answer ;)